# Turning multiple similar pages into one page?

Tags: jquery, mustache

I have multiple pages with similarly worded questions and answers. Right now I have Question1 as one html page with it's own JS file which when the user clicks submit goes to Question2, another html page with its own JS file.

These pages/questions are all extremely similar. What is the best way to turn them all into one page that reloads with new content after every question. I'm thinking similar to DuoLingo, who say they use mustache templates with jquery/backbone.js.

I am struggling to find any info on how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried reading through the documentation for [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), and [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)?  What *exactly* are you stuck on?

Comment: This is a broad, opinion-based question. Sounds to me like you want a server-side technology, like php or asp.net plus a database, but even that is an opinion.

Comment: Sorry, meant to ask would mustache+jquery do the job?

Comment: @JasonP I'm asking if would this be an example of the right technology

Comment: @par Unfortunately, questions that rely on opinion based answers are not what stackoverflow is meant for, so you probably will not get a lot if any answers. That being said, I think you're on the right track. You could do what you're proposing with the technologies you listed. If this is a simple application, mustache and backbone might be overkill. I would advise using backbone if you need database CRUD (which you probably don't). Mustache is great if you need easily maintained template files. jQuery is nice, but even javascript alone would work, but that is all just my *opinion*. :P

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks!

Comment: @par another good term to look up is SPA - single page application. a lot of them are big tools and probably overkill. maybe you can find a really small one, or even a pre-made questionnaire app/software. i've never used mustache for form-submission, sry.